# JQuery .each not looping through all elements with class

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, each

I am working on a navigation solution for heavily customized pages hosted on a content management platform that my employer uses.

I am trying to build a function that loops through all elements with a specific class, reads a data store value, then loads an external resource based on that value into a container div.

While the function works for the FIRST match, it stops at that point - no iteration through the rest of the document. The function itself is called in a separate $(document).ready(function() block, as I have several functions running at page load.

EDIT: Had outdated code from playing with different things, current code below.

Javascript:

```
 function loadNavigation() {
 $('.topLevelNav').each(function () {
 var topLevelNavIndex = $(this).data('nav-index')+1;
 var topLevelNavItem = spaceMainContent + " table tr:nth-child(" + topLevelNavIndex + ") td:nth-child(2)";
 $(this).children().first().load(topLevelNavItem);
});
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="topLevelNav" data-nav-index="1">Main
 <div>Container</div>
<div class="subLevelNav" data-nav-index ="3">Sub<div>Container</div></div>
<div class="subLevelNav" data-nav-index ="4">Sub<div>Container</div></div>
<div class="subLevelNav" data-nav-index ="5">Sub<div>Container</div></div>
<div class="subLevelNav" data-nav-index ="6">Sub<div>Container</div></div>
<div class="subLevelNav" data-nav-index ="2">Sub<div>Container</div></div>
</div>
<div class="topLevelNav" data-nav-index ="2">Main
<div>Container</div>
<div class="subLevelNav" data-nav-index ="3">Sub<div>Container</div></div>
<div class="subLevelNav" data-nav-index ="5">Sub<div>Container</div></div>
<div class="subLevelNav" data-nav-index ="2">Sub<div>Container</div></div>
</div>
<div class="topLevelNav" data-nav-index ="3">Main
<div>Container</div>
<div class="subLevelNav" data-nav-index ="2">Sub<div>Container</div></div>
</div>
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why it is stopping after that first match, but I am also not a smart man. Any thoughts?

Comment: Your code `$('.topLevelNav').each` should iterate over all your `.topLevelNav` elements, of which I see exactly one

Comment: Do you actually have more than one `topLevelNav`-class `div` or are all the other ones `topLevelNav2`-class?

Comment: You only have one .topLevelNav class defined.

Comment: Also, do you want to iterate over the child elements, if so, your selector is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to process the sublevelnavs, your selector is wrong. Change it to either

```
$('.topLevelNav .subLevelNav').each(function () {
```

if you want to iterate through only the subLevelNavs in the top level one

or

```
$('.subLevelNav').each(function () {
```

if you want to iterate through every sub level navigation